# Is get_result() a required call for put_async() in Google App Engine

Tags: python, google-app-engine, asynchronous, google-cloud-datastore

With the new release of GAE 1.5.0, we now have an easy way to do async datastore calls. Are we required to call `get_result()` after calling 
'[put_async](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/functions.html#put_async)'?

For example, if I have an model called `MyLogData`, can I just call:

```
put_async(MyLogData(text="My Text"))
```

right before my handler returns without calling the matching `get_result()`?
Does GAE automatically block on any pending calls before sending the result to the client?

Note that I don't really care to handle error conditions. i.e. I don't mind if some of these puts fail.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't think there is any sure way to know if `get_result()` is required unless someone on the GAE team verifies this, but I think it's not needed. Here is how I tested it.

I wrote a simple handler:

```
class DB_TempTestModel(db.Model):
    data = db.BlobProperty()

class MyHandler(webapp.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        starttime = datetime.datetime.now()
        lots_of_data = ' '*500000
        if self.request.get('a') == '1':
            db.put(DB_TempTestModel(data=lots_of_data))
            db.put(DB_TempTestModel(data=lots_of_data))
            db.put(DB_TempTestModel(data=lots_of_data))
            db.put(DB_TempTestModel(data=lots_of_data))
        if self.request.get('a') == '2':
            db.put_async(DB_TempTestModel(data=lots_of_data))
            db.put_async(DB_TempTestModel(data=lots_of_data))
            db.put_async(DB_TempTestModel(data=lots_of_data))
            db.put_async(DB_TempTestModel(data=lots_of_data))
        self.response.out.write(str(datetime.datetime.now()-starttime))
```

I ran it a bunch of times on a High Replication Application.

The data was always there, making me believe that unless there is a failure in the datastore side of things (unlikely), it's gonna be written.

Here's the interesting part.  When the data is written with `put_async()` (`?a=2`), the amount of time (to process the request) was on average about 2 to 3 times as fast as `put()`(`?a=1`) (not a very scientific test - just eyeballing it).

But the `cpu_ms` and `api_cpu_ms` were the same for both `?a=1` and `?a=2`.

From the logs:

`ms=440 cpu_ms=627 api_cpu_ms=580 cpm_usd=0.036244`

vs

`ms=149 cpu_ms=627 api_cpu_ms=580 cpm_usd=0.036244`

On the client side, looking at the network latency of the requests, it showed the same results, i.e. `?a=2' requests were at least 2 times faster. Definitely a win on the client side... but it seems to not have any gain on the server side.

Anyone on the GAE team care to comment?

Answer (score 3):

`db.put_async` works fine without `get_result` **when deployed** (in fire-and-forget style) but in [locally it won't take action until `get_result`](http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=7748) gets called [more context](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7244081/appengine-put-async-doesnt-work-at-least-in-the-development-server/7250613#7250613)

Comment: It's not a bug; it's documented behavior. dev_appserver is single-threaded and async urlfetch is merely simulated.

Comment: @Wooble could point me to the documentation that sais about that special local development server behaviour ? I will straight close the thicket with that link (BTW: i was referring to ``db.put_async`` and 0  efect)

Comment: Err, I misread; this behavior for asych urlfetch is documented; it appears to be undocumented for async datastore (although the single-threadedness of dev_appserver is itself documented, there seems to be no mention in the docs of the async behavior.)

Comment: @Wooble, thanks - All I could find even in context of ``urlfetch.make_fetch_call`` does not suggest that the call will not run until ``rpc.get_result`` with local development "The development server does not make asynchronous URL fetch calls in the background. Instead, it performs the URL fetch synchronously when the RPC object's ``wait()`` method is called..." from https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/urlfetch/asynchronousrequests . I would ether expect one more line in docs or a local hack that async or not would bring same results in the end (datastore). Thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

I dunno, but this works:

```
import datetime
from google.appengine.api import urlfetch

def main():
  rpc = urlfetch.create_rpc()
  urlfetch.make_fetch_call(rpc, "some://artificially/slow.url")
  print "Content-type: text/plain"
  print
  print str(datetime.datetime.now())

if __name__ == '__main__':
  main()
```

The remote URL sleeps 3 seconds and then sends me an email. The App Engine handler returns immediately, and the remote URL completes as expected. Since both services abstract the same underlying RPC framework, I would guess the datastore behaves similarly.

Good question, though. Perhaps Nick or another Googler can answer definitively.