# Appengine: put_async doesn't work (at least in the development server)?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

**NOTE**:
IT DOES WORK IN PRODUCTION. I MEAN, WHEN I UPLOAD THE APPLICATION IT JUST WORKS FINE. THE PROBLEM IS IN THE DEVELOPMENT SERVER.

Here is some code that can show you what i'm trying to do:

```
e = Employee(key_name = 'some_key_name',name='John Bonham')
db.put_async(e)
```

If i do it, and after some time i try to get it

```
e = Employee.get_by_key_name('some_key_name') # e is None
```

It doesn't work. e is None! But, if i do this:

```
e = Employee(key_name = 'some_key_name',name='John Bonham')
op = db.put_async(e)
op.get_result()
```

It works fine.

What am i missing?

**Important Note: I wait some time to check if the object is created! I don't do get after the call put_async. But, it still doesn't work, even a minute after. I'm in the Development Server!**

Comment: Is this put_async within a transaction? Have you tried it within a transaction to see if the transaction blocking makes it work like `get_result()`? Can you show more of your actual code where you're making this call?

Comment: @Steve i've not tried it within a transaction, i'll do in a minute. There's nothing much to show, trying with the "toy" code i posted doesn't work neither.I'll try the transaction, thank you for your interest.

Comment: @Steve, it actually works within the transaction. The problem is that it would block my execution the same way as with put() if i need to put objects from different entity groups. It's too weird. What's going on?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you don't call `.wait()` or `.get_result()` on an RPC, there is no way to guarantee it's completed. In the case of the `dev_appserver`, which is not multi-threaded, the actual work is done when you call those methods - it's not actually asynchronous in development, only in production.

Comment: Thank you nick. It's actually pretty weird. Is it any way of fixing it, becouse this way i've to code my app thinking that in the production enviroment is going to work, but in the dev_appserver i'll not see it working.

Comment: @santiagobasulto You shouldn't rely on it working in production, either. Not calling `wait()` or `get_result()` on your RPCs is a bug - why would you want to do this anyway?

Comment: @Nick thank you. I'm building a "multiple" URL Shrotener. A user submits some URLs and gets a URL with the code. You can see it working here: http://multbe.appspot.com/ You can see the code to get the tiny URL here (from line 70, shorten method): https://github.com/santiagobasulto/mult.be/blob/master/app/views.py What i do is calculate the tiny code and return it to the user, and make the URLs save through put_async.

Comment: @santiagobasulto You still need to wait on the RPCs before returning to the user. If you don't, the infrastructure will do so anyway - responses can't be returned while there are outstanding RPCs.

Comment: Where is this behavior documented? There's no mention of .wait() here: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/async

Comment: @NickJohnson please can you confirm whether "You still need to wait on the RPCs before returning to the user. If you don't, the infrastructure will do so anyway" is still the case? (since you wrote that 4 years ago, and I dont see any mention of it in the docs). Regarding your question (why would you want to do this anyway?) I'd hoped to use put_async for writing non-critical logging data, while making response as quick as possible (e.g. logging homepage visit) thanks.

Comment: @tom I don't work on App Engine any longer, so I can't check quickly, but I don't expect it's changed. You could test it yourself pretty easily, though!

Comment: Thanks. @NickJohnson how would I test that? I.e. how can I know whether the infrastructure is waiting? By just observing the response time over a large number of tests?

Comment: @tom Do something you know is expensive, like a very large put, and observe if it returns immediately or takes a long time.