# put_async slow in Google App Engine

Tags: python, google-app-engine, datastore

I recently replaced many sycnronous db.put calls in an appengine app w/ the async calls. I don't need to use this data for the rest of the request, so initially I was just calling the put_async function in a fire-and-forget manner. Then I came across this post on SO:
[Appengine: put_async doesn't work (at least in the development server)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7244081/appengine-put-async-doesnt-work-at-least-in-the-development-server) , and the response from an app engine engineer saying you have to call wait or get_result on the async object to guarantee it's written.

So in my testing all the put_async calls were working fine, but I wanted to be sure so I added a global module with a variable that I access across all other modules and store the async ref in every time a call was made to put_async in the app. ie:
APP_GLOBALS.async_db_calls.append( db.put_async( whatever_db_model ) )

Then I registered a shutdown function with atexit that iterates over all the asycn calls for this request and calls wait() on them to guarantee they were written to the datastore.

This *works* but I noticed an extreme slowdown in performance after this change... Does anybody have any insights on this, or know a better way to go about using the asycncalls for write without having the shutdown function?

Comment: Er, can you elaborate on why you need the shutdown function? The question you linked to about `put_async` didn't have anything about it being required...

Comment: Just using it for convenience as a single place after the response is finished to finalize all the async calls (versus piecemealing wait/get_result calls all over after the async calls)

Comment: Why do you feel the need to "finalize" them?

Comment: Whoops.. I referenced the wrong SO question initially. Just fixed it. As you will see from the question, Nick states that's it is necessary to guarantee the writes succeed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The NDB API has features that will greatly assist you with this. However, you will always have to wait for the RPC calls to finish before the request is finished, this is not something you can avoid. Calling the *_async counterparts of the datastore API does not let you do work outside of requests.

http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/async.html

Comment: So if I understand correctly, basically my only options other than checking that all RPCs are done in the shutdown function are: 1) handle each 'futures' object individually wherever it makes sense for that context, or 2) decorate ALL my handler functions with @context.toplevel.

Comment: Upon further research, NDB will not work for most of my data store, as it doesn't support many properties I widely use (such as ReferenceProperty)

Comment: you'll always want to decorate with the @context.toplevel, this lets you go about your code without having to track the async calls you make and also lets you create tasklets for further concurrency. If you need to guarantee your writes, then your only option, AFAIK, is to go through each future and call get_result() and watch for exceptions. This might not be any better than your current method (though only testing will tell) but at least its provided by the SDK and can possibly simplify your code. Try doing a small portion of your code and check to see if it helps.

Comment: There is a work around for reference properties: http://groups.google.com/group/appengine-ndb-discuss/browse_thread/thread/c2036d00cc22ac9a, you could migrate to a new property name and use a @property decorator on a function for the original property name to cover this new syntax without having to update all of your code. I'm sure you know your code best though and migrating to the NDB API is no easy task for an established and in-production app!

Comment: Thanks for your comments - Explored NDB docs some more, it would be a very large project to convert my datastore to ndb. In the meantime, I am having trouble getting @context.toplevel to work. Using python 2.7, webapp2 and decorating the dispatch function... is the context decorator only available w/ the NDB api?

Comment: The context decorator is only meant to be used with the NDB API, yes. Sorry if I was unclear on that previously.